# High Traffic & Excessive Script Execution Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a container-bound Apps Script Project contained to a Form Response Google Sheet, triggered on form submit. The script runs as me. I'm dealing with execution runtimes 6-8x the nominal run time during peak hours of the day, which seems largely correlated to increased traffic of form submissions. The program follows this series of steps:

1. Form response collects a string of information and triggers the Apps Script Project to execute
2. Project creates a copy of a complex Google sheet of a few tabs and a lot of complex formulas
3. Project pastes the string collected from the form response into this google sheet copy, flushes the sheet, and then returns a string of results calculated within the sheet
4. Google sheet file is named and the Project creates a unique Drive folder where this sheet eventually gets moved to.
5. Run complete

The Project performs a wide variety of getValue and SetValue calls throughout the run as it's updating cell values or reading calculated results. Over the last year, I've improved optimization in many ways (i.e. batch calls to getValues or setValues, batch API calls, etc). It's normal run time is 25-45 seconds, but increases to 200+ seconds during my company's peak business hours. Using logs, there is no one particular step that gets hung up. But rather the script lags in all aspects (When it creates the file copy, SpreadsheetApp.flush(), append or delete rows in google other sheets it references by Sheet ID, etc). Although, I'll say a common reason for a failed execution returns the error message "Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id..." But most of the executions complete successfully, just after a lengthy run.

It seems there is a clear correlation between execution time and traffic. So my questions are:

1. Can anyone confirm that theory?
2. Is there a way I can increase the service's bandwidth for my project?
3. Is there a better alternative to having the script run as me? (mind you I'm performing the rest of my job using Chrome throughout the day while this program continues to automatically run in the background)
4. This is an Apps Script managed project; it is not tied to a personal GCP Project. Is that a potential factor at play here?

Comment: Follow best practices in coding and consider the use of Lock Service if needed.  There are several examples of such questions on this forum.  You should be able to find examples that you can adapt for your needs or just write it yourself.

Comment: Does the issue stem from multiple people are submitting the form at once? What kind of processing gets done on form submit? As Cooper suggested using a [script lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) in your code will help to mitigate the first issue - but as for script executions, it may be better to queue submissions and go through the queue rather than attempting many executions at once ([simultaneous executions are limited to 30](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)). But this depends on what processing is done.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Lock Service - I wasn't aware of that and will read into it. @RafaGuillermo The form is submitted via a POST http request from Microsoft Excel files used by 250+ people across the U.S. So 250+ users submitting requests, but each Script run triggered is run as ME, not them. On Average, this yields a form submission and subsequent Script execution every 5-9 seconds during PEAK hours of the day. With a nominal runtime of 25-50 seconds, that means 5-8 concurrent Script Runs during peak hours. This team has volume goals to hit, so queuing submissions is not an option.

Comment: Correction. There is a form submission every 20-40 seconds during PEAK hours, translating to 2-3 concurrent script executions. Not 5-8 concurrent executions.